# How to get string between between two charaters(e.g "|this|that|")

Tags: java, string, split

this is my string `"|Apple| Ball |Cat|Dog|"`

I am using this pattern

```
p = Pattern.compile("\\|(.*?)\\|")
```

but result I am getting :

```
Apple
Cat
```

`Ball` and Dog is ignored

Comment: Try with this `p = Pattern.compile("\|(.*?)")`

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Wouldn't a simple `split("\\|")` be sufficient?

Comment: @SanjaySs wouldn't that be empty string after `|`?

Comment: use `split` as [suggested by *deHaar*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58814898/#comment103907854_58814898) (even consider `string.split("\\|", -1)` to get trailing empty strings); or, `Pattern.compile("\\|([^|]*)")`, if preferred/required

Comment: Note: drawback of `split`: will return an additional empty string at start (index 0) and, if using second negative argument, one at end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex `(?=\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|)`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=\\|\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\|)");
```

Outputs

```
Apple
Ball
Cat
Dog
```

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/99WM97/1) and [**ideone demo**](https://www.ideone.com/HCSDQC)

---

Second solution by using `split` like so :

```
String regex = "\\s*\\|\\s*";
String[] result = str.replaceFirst(regex, "").split(regex);
```

Comment: @SanjaySs sorry my mistake, I don't read the question very well, I thought the OP want to ignore the fields which contains spaces in start or end, I fix it now

Answer (score 2):

I think the best in your case would be to use split function rather than a pattern:

```
 String str = "|Apple| Ball |Cat|Dog|";

 String[] splitted = str.split("\\|");

 //str[0] == "Apple", str[1] == "Ball" ...
```

EDIT: if your string starts and ends with "|", then you might use a substring before splitting:

```
 String str = "|Apple| Ball |Cat|Dog|";

 str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

 String[] splitted = str.split("\\|");

 //str[0] == "Apple", str[1] == "Ball" ...
```

This way we make sure not to have "empty" string at the beginning and end of splitted array.

Answer (score 2):

My idea replace `|` become `space` and split string

```
String str = "|Apple| Ball |Cat|Dog|";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("\\|", " ").split("\\s+");
```

Test

```
for (String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s); // Apple Ball Cat Dog
}
```

Comment: Why not to split using "|" directly?

Comment: Because another person did above.